# Read Double From a .txt File into an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

So we have this program where we have to read double values from a text file into a double ArrayList and make certain calculations.

example of the text file:

**Note:** there's space between the date and the double values

```
5/05/1998 4.4

1/01/1999 -4.123
```

the problem is that i'm getting is as below:

> "NumberFormatException for input string: 1/2/1950 0.0258" error.

Here's my code:

```
public static void value() throws java.io.IOException{
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("SP500-Weekly.txt")));
        ArrayList<Double>list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] r = line.split("    ");
            for(int i=0; i<r.length; i++){
                double val = Double.parseDouble(r[i]);
                list.add(val);
            }
        }br.close();
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you format the value in text file to be exactly what you are trying to load? Are each record present in new line?

Comment: yes every record is in a new line.

Comment: And what is your output supposed to be like? It is all doubles values in a single list?

Comment: Why are you splitting by 4 spaces? Shouldn't you split by single space and read only the second part of the result?

Comment: @stackFan, the doubles should be stored in a arraylist and then we have to access one of those randomly using Double value = data.get(r.nextInt(data.size()));.

Comment: What is the string which gives this exception, exactly? Try debugger or debug prints.

Comment: i tried using single space this is the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/"

Comment: Tip: Where feasible, serialize a date in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: YYYY-MM-DD. `java.time.LocalDate.parse( "2018-09-04" )` & `localDate.toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need the `double` value present on each line and want to add it into a `List<Double>`. Based off of your input, second value is always your double value, but you are trying to parse first value as well which is a date and `Double.parseDouble()` cannot parse characters that comes in a date such as `/`, thus you ran into exception. If the double value is what you need then do it simply as :

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( new File( "SP500-Weekly.txt"" ) ) );
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        String line;

        while ( ( line = br.readLine( ) ) != null ) {

            String[] r = line.split( "\\s+" );
            list.add( Double.parseDouble( r[ 1 ] ) );
        }
        br.close( );
        System.out.println( list.size( ) );
    } catch ( IOException io ) {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
```

You can then play around with `list` variable as your wish.

Also if you want to be more specific and check if it's actually number/double for second value then I'd do following to add a regex which will make sure that the second value is number (with or without `-` sign) as below:

```
while ( ( line = br.readLine( ) ) != null ) {
            String[] r = line.split( "\\s+" );
            for ( String string: r ) {
                if ( string.matches( "^-?[0-9]?.?[0-9]+" ) ) {
                    list.add( Double.parseDouble( r[ 1 ] ) );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Closing your resources manually or yet better using a try with resources would have been very nice. Also coding to the implementation rather than the interface is not correct.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex thanks for suggestion. Initially I wrote to address the main issue OP was having. Now the code has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and up to date implementation of this using `java.nio` and pure Java 8 would the following.

```
private static List<Double> readDoubles(final String fileName) {
   try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return stream.map(s -> s.split("\\s+")[1])
                .map(Double::parseDouble)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Implementation also takes the liberty of using `try-with-resources` to auto manager the various resources.

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTCODE:

```
import java.util.List;
class Sample extends SimulateMarket{
    public static void value(){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("SP500-Weekly.txt")));
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] r = line.split("\\s+");
            list.add(Double.parseDouble(r[1]));
        }br.close();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        System.out.println(list.get(randomIndex));
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This also obviously wrong. You catch and throw the same exception. Either do one of them. Also you're still using the concrete implementation for the initialization of the list.

Comment: The catch/throw thing i've fixed; however, i'm learning java basics at my college and i'm not familiar with the term "concrete implementation."

Comment: This is referring to this `ArrayList<Double>list = new ArrayList<Double>();`. Use this `List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();` instead.